# Data populated in firefox but not in IE(All version)

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below Javascript code is working fine and displaying data in Firefox but in IE it is not showing anything.

```
function AddToTable(tblID, dataObject)
{
    for (var count = 0; count < dataObject.length; count++)
    {
        var row = document.createElement("TR");
        row.setAttribute("className","lineHeight");

        var cell = document.createElement("TD");
        var cell1 = document.createElement("TD");

        cell.setAttribute("align" , "center");
        cell.setAttribute("width" , "3%");
        cell1.innerHTML = "<b>* </b>" + dataObject[count];

        row.appendChild(cell);
        row.appendChild(cell1);
        tblID.appendChild(row);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It working fine for me now..with **jQuery**
Its now time to learn jQuery well..Here is the code piece..
It was not working in javascript because "createElement" was not true for JS.

```
function AddToTable(tblID, decodedValue)
{
    var $jAdd = jQuery.noConflict();
    var row= $jAdd("<tr/>").attr("className","lineHeight");
    var cell = $jAdd("<td/>").attr({"align" : "center","width" : "3%"});
    var cell1 = $jAdd("<td/>").html("<b>* </b>" + decodedValue);
    row.append(cell);
    row.append(cell1);
    $jAdd(tblID).append(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbsandeep/eUnnc/)

It is working in IE as well (IE10). Compatibility mode - IE9 & IE8 works, IE7 - doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Sandeep for your time..your fiddle is working as you said.But i am still not able to find a reason why my code is not working in IE..Any idea what else can be going wrong here

Comment: Can you share your "dataObject" contents?

Comment: I have also tried sending only string to the dataobject but same result..not showing anything